# How to get index of name attribute from same name of multiple elements.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some input fields, having same names but I only want to get the value of index of each input like this

```
<input type="text" name="op_price[20]" value="20.00" size="3"  >
<input type="text" name="op_price[2]" value="13" size="3">
<input type="text" name="op_price[14]" value="12" size="3">
```

So, for example I only wants to get 20, 2, 14 from op_price name attribute, is their any JS or jquery method to do this

Comment: use regex, or string index search to find the relevant value from the attribute.

Comment: hmm, can you please give me code or link something that will be really helpful thanks

Comment: you can see my comment or can use this code                         var name="op_price[20]"  

name.replace(/op_price\[(\d*)?]/gi, $1); this code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return the indexes in an array:

```
var indexes = $('[name^="op_price"]').map(function(){
    return this.name.match(/\d+/);
}).get();

console.log(indexes); // ["20", "2", "14"]
```

Comment: thanks!! you save my day.. but please tell me why you are using .get()

Comment: @SaketBisht `map()` produces a new jQuery object, you call `get()` to get the native array

Answer (score 0):

Use [attributeContains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Ex from docs :

```
$( "input[name*='man']" ).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're not going to change the name of your input fields, may be you can iterate through a loop to get all the values? Try this:

```
for(i=0;document.getElementById('op_price['+i+']';i++)
 alert(document.getElementById('op_price['+i+']');
```

this will give you the value of the ith input field in each iteration of the loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $("input:text").attr("name");
name = name.replace("op_price[", "").replace("]", "");
alert(name);
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/vDVTV/)**

Answer (score 0):

like if you get your name property

```
   var name="op_price[20]"  

name.replace(/op_price\[(\d*)?]/gi, $1);
```

then op_price[20] replace with 20